# Does FlashPlayer support ScreenVideo codec?

Tags: flash

I have  swf file with embedded movie encoded with ScreenVideo codec,
swf spec says FP supports it,  but I can't see any frame.

Comment: Are you sure you have the right Flash Player version? Can you put up a live example and a link to the swf specs?

Comment: yes, i have the latest player from Adobe.
the sample file can be downloaded from this page, it's in attachment to the first post http://forums.adobe.com/thread/531985
spec lays here http://www.adobe.com/devnet/swf/pdf/swf_file_format_spec_v10.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not, according to:
http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/402/kb402866.html

It does according to swf spec.

Which truth is real?

Comment: All the Flash Players that I have tested support it.